# SQL Query not working with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all the tiny query works but I need to put some joins in the middle of it to make a condition.
The tiny query is the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(vis.id), country.cod
FROM visits AS vis, countries AS country
WHERE country.description = vis.country
GROUP BY country.cod
```

The problem now is that I need to add another condition in the `where` clause, and this condition comes, necessarily from a join in two tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(vis.id), country.cod
FROM visits AS vis, countries AS country
INNER JOIN products AS prod ON prod.id = vis.id_product
INNER JOIN customers AS cust ON cust.id = prod.id_customer
WHERE country.description = visit.country AND prod.id_customer = 13
GROUP BY country.cod
```

The error I receive is:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'vis.id_product' in 'on clause'
```

And trust me, that field exists. Also, I've tried, just for testing, to put other fields instead of `id_product` and the error is the same.

Comment: Does your visits table have an `id_product` field?  Please post table structure (and possible sample data with desired results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given the table `visits` the alias `vis`.  Now you need to use it.

```
SELECT COUNT(vis.id), country.cod
FROM visits AS vis JOIN
     countries AS country
     ON  country.description = vis.country JOIN
     products AS prod
     ON prod.id = vis.id_product JOIN
     customers AS cust
     ON cust.id = prod.id_customer
WHERE prod.id_customer = 13
GROUP BY country.cod;
```

In addition, you are mixing implicit and explicit joins.  Only use explicit joins, where the join conditions go in the `on` clause and not in the `where` clause.  A simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: The problem was not the alias `vis`, I mistyped it while creating the topic. 
The solution was to JOIN the `description` with `country`. 
I will accept your answer in 7 minutes.